# How do I call a class into a class from main? and keep the output values?

Tags: class, integer

I have 3 classes. Main, ZombieEncounter and  inventory.

This is my main: pastebin.com/9uyDsPTT

This is my inventory: http://pastebin.com/uESNkX5p

This is my zombieEncounter: http://pastebin.com/77U7gv2Z *Not completed yet*.

If I make another class titled "gun" *with int for ammo and clip size*. Can I add that class to the inventory through class main? So that I can call the inventory and use it in zombieEncounter class. *Also* how would I be able to save the int when zombieEncounter uses the class gun? *Lets say* I use "x" amount of ammo, how do I save the end result of the clip size/ammo usage?

Sorry for the confusing question..I'm still new at this and I think it'll be hard to paste the source in a Code Sample.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this would be to give your `ZombieEncounter` class, a variable (maybe private?) of type `Inventory` and assign it a value in the constructor. Then you can create an `Inventory` and a `ZombieEncounter` object inside your main and then pass the `Inventory` object to the `ZombieEncounter`'s constructor.

For the saving part you have to provide more information about how you want to implement it. For example you can save that on a global variable or maybe in a file.

(note that it is good practice to change to private every class variable and create setters/getters for each one of them)

Comment: What do you mean by making a **private variable** of **type inventory** and assign it a value in the **constructor**? I _think_ I understand the creating an object inside main class **BUT** you lost me at passing the **inventory** object to the **zombieEncounter** constructor.

Comment: First of all you have to create a constructor in your ZombieEncounter class. do you know what a constructor is or you actually need further help with that?

Comment: Sorry, I do need help with that. I never seen a constructor before. Sorry for the hassle and thanks.

Comment: Let me give you some help with that. A constructor is a function that gets called every time an object of a class is created. For example lets say i have a class named Foo with a variable name fooVar. Its constructor must be a function with no return value, just the name of the class and maybe some parameters. Actual Code:
`public class Foo() 
{ 
    private int fooVar;
    public Foo() 
    { 
        fooVar = 15;
    } 
}`
This is what it looks like, although it is a big matter to be discussed in a comment. Do some study on that it will improve your skills a lot.

Comment: Check this post for further reading:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html

Comment: If you are stuck and unable to find a way to solve this feel free to add a comment and ill be glad to help you (maybe join a chat room and discuss your implementation).

Comment: thank you for the post I'll see what I can tweak with constructors :)

Comment: I'm still stuck after reading and looking up minor tutorials of Constructors on YT. I don't understand how the concept will help me use data and save the new value. I also can't join a chat room because Java chat says I need 20 reputation.

Comment: Well constructors is the easiest way to do it and its fundamental for object-oriented-programming languages, such as java. If you continue learning programming you will encounter it sooner or later. I believe it is worth it to take some time (maybe some days) and practice how to use constructors, private fields in classes and how to use a class in another class and after that continue your game. It will change the way you think and you will see that the game code will be a lot easier. Just find a good post-tutorial and some practice code and work on it. This is what works best for me!

Comment: This post seems good as well: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Dont rush, take all the time u need to understand it.